# UIWebView not evaluating java script using method stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am having trouble evaluating youtube api javascript commands from a UIWebView

The commands are evaluating correctly in Safari and Firefox

the webview is initialized with options

```
allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
```

The Html I am loading is:

```
<div id="player"></div>

<script>
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    //playerVars: { 'autoplay': 0, 'modestbranding': 1, 'rel': 0, 'showinfo': 0, 'iv_load_policy': 3, 'controls': 1, 'playsinline':1 },
    var configuration = {
        playerVars: {
            'playsinline':1,
            'showinfo': 0,
            'modestbranding': 1
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    };

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

function setup(key, value) {
    configuration[key] = value;
}

function configurePlayer(key, value) {
    configuration.playerVars[key] = value;
}
// area for the code injection
setup('videoId', 'cDhlx60nTCU');
setup('startingTime', 10);
setup('autoPlay' , true);
setup('width', 400);
setup('height', 200);
configurePlayer('controls', true);


var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', configuration);
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    if (configuration['autoPlay']) {
        if (configuration['startingTime']) {
            player.playVideoAt(configuration['startingTime']);
        } else {
            event.target.playVideo();
        }
    }
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        // Do something...
    }
}

function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
    return "OK";
}
</script>
Printing description of html:
<div id="player"></div>

<script>
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    //playerVars: { 'autoplay': 0, 'modestbranding': 1, 'rel': 0, 'showinfo': 0, 'iv_load_policy': 3, 'controls': 1, 'playsinline':1 },
    var configuration = {
        playerVars: {
            'playsinline':1,
            'showinfo': 0,
            'modestbranding': 1
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    };

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

function setup(key, value) {
    configuration[key] = value;
}

function configurePlayer(key, value) {
    configuration.playerVars[key] = value;
}
// area for the code injection
setup('videoId', 'cDhlx60nTCU');
setup('startingTime', 0);
setup('autoPlay' , true);
setup('width', 320);
setup('height', 288);
configurePlayer('controls', true);


var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', configuration);
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    if (configuration['autoPlay']) {
        if (configuration['startingTime']) {
            player.playVideoAt(configuration['startingTime']);
        } else {
            event.target.playVideo();
        }
    }
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        // Do something...
    }
}

function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
    return "OK";
}
</script>
```

I am loading the webview page with this

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.webview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"html"]];
}
```

after the webview delegate calls `webViewDidFinishLoad`

I tried calling methods on the player with this syntax

```
-(void)pause
{
    [self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"player.pauseVideo();"];
}
```

Are there possibly any flags that are interfering with the java script evaluation?

Comment: Have you tried using the web debugger in Safari or Chrome to send the same javascript to the page?

Comment: Yes. When I run the page in the simulator and debug with safari , the 'player' object is not defined with the right methods - it only has internal properties and not the api methods. But when I load the page in chrome/firefox/safari everything is defined properly

Comment: I can't see anything here that jumps out at you. I want you to try one more thing before I post my sample code which DOES work: surround the <div> with valid HTML. Example:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
        <div id="player"></div>

Comment: Just tested my script without valid HTML. Some stuff works, some other stuff does not, but I am not seeing the exact problem. Give this a try and post the outcome.

Comment: I tried that as well. I might not have posted it but it doesn't help me out

Comment: Would it help if i post my example project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"html"]];
```

to this:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]];
```

I've noticed that `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` won't work when you don't use a valid URL (you'll see that this also happens when you use `NULL` as the value. I just tested your code with both versions, and found that the version with `about:blank` will correctly evaluate JavaScript, whereas the version with `html` as the NSURL value will not.

Comment: I want to reopen a question for you. I tried this method and everything was working fine for a while. Now it has stopped playing inline when autoplay is set to 'true'. When set to true the youtube video doesn't play - there is just a black screen. when I set autoplay to 'false' the video plays inline OK

Comment: Also as soon as I turn off autoplaying - the video will not play inline and only plays full screen

Comment: You should probably close this question and start a new one. We use StackOverflow to make it easier for other people with the same question to find answers, and doing things this way makes it difficult.

Comment: the about:blank is not working for me, any other ideas?